# Listen for power button long press from inside a service

Tags: android, android-service, onkeydown

I was able to override the long pressed power button from inside an activity. But Iwanted it inside a service. Is it possible to do this listening for key events inside a service.

Here is the code within the activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER){
         Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
         sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
         return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

How can I achieve it inside of a Service.

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)